# Bad performance with window function in streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, window-functions

I use Spark 2.0.2, Kafka 0.10.1 and the spark-streaming-kafka-0-8 integration. I want to do the following:

I extract features in a streaming job out of NetFlow connections and than apply the records to a k-means model. Some of the features are simple ones which are calculated directly from the record. But I also have more complex features which depend on records from a specified time window before. They count how many connections in the last second were to the same host or service as the current one. I decided to use the SQL window functions for this.

So I build window specifications:

```scala
val hostCountWindow = Window.partitionBy("plainrecord.ip_dst").orderBy(desc("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-1L, 0L)
val serviceCountWindow = Window.partitionBy("service").orderBy(desc("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-1L, 0L)
```

And a function which is called to extract this features on every batch:

```scala
def extractTrafficFeatures(dataset: Dataset[Row]) = {
  dataset
    .withColumn("host_count", count(dataset("plainrecord.ip_dst")).over(hostCountWindow))
    .withColumn("srv_count", count(dataset("service")).over(serviceCountWindow))
}
```

And use this function as follows

```scala
stream.map(...).map(...).foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val dataframe = rdd.toDF(featureHeaders: _*).transform(extractTrafficFeatures(_))
  ...
}
```

The problem is that this has a very bad performance. A batch needs between 1 and 3 seconds for a average input rate of less than 100 records per second. I guess it comes from the partitioning, which produces a lot of shuffling?

I tried to use the RDD API and `countByValueAndWindow()`. This seems to be much faster, but the code looks way nicer and cleaner with the DataFrame API.

Is there a better way to calculate these features on the streaming data? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Relatively low performance is to be expected here. Your code has to shuffle and sort data twice, once for:

```
Window
  .partitionBy("plainrecord.ip_dst")
  .orderBy(desc("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-1L, 0L)
```

and once for:

```
Window
  .partitionBy("service")
  .orderBy(desc("timestamp")).rangeBetween(-1L, 0L)
```

This will have a huge impact on the runtime and if these are the hard requirements you won't be able to do much better.